# How to create a dependent cusom option

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I need to  display custom option only if previous custom option selection is 'Yes'. Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is part of Magento.  There is an extension by MageWorx that might help you.  I haven't tried it but I've been looking at it for Magento 2.1
http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html